# TypeScript - `+null` vs `Number(null)`

Tags: typescript

tsconfig.json:

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "strict": true,
    "target": "ESNext"
  }
}
```

Why `+null` throws `Object is possibly 'null'` and `Number(null)` works fine.

Comment: In this case this is it https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/21574

Comment: @Timothy, you should post an answer when you have the time